# Запуск приложения на удаленном сервере без дополнительного ПО

Tags: сервер, администрирование, клиент-сервер, powershell

Друзья привет. Есть необходимость запустить консольное приложение на удаленном сервере на Windows 10. Из сложностей: не должно быть доп ПО(psexec и тп.). Есть ли возможность сделать это средствами, допустим, powershell? Мне удалось подключиться к удаленному серверу и взять с него инфу по запущенным процессам через powershell кодом ниже, значит подключиться можно,но запустить приложение я так и не смог(ошибка доступа).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}
```

Или может это можно сделать кодом c# какими нибудь секретными библиотечками?

Comment: При чем тут C#? На вашем месте я бы на сервере поднял бы JSON-RPC (или аналог) и передавал бы ему заранее заготовленные команды. А сейчас вы просто ищите дыру в безопасности операционных систем.

Comment: аналог ssh наверное нужно, но раз уж вы получили Get-Process, то наверное в одном домене?

Comment: Если у вас получилось Get-Process запустить - значит, вы можете запустить что угодно, если только оно не запрещено политиками. Проверяйте какие права есть у того пользователя, под аккаунтом которого вы подключились к серверу.

Comment: @eri да, в одном домене

Comment: так может запускать политикой домена вместо этого?

Comment: Ну так это. WinRM же. Через него работает и ansible в том числе. Ещё вопрос. Почему "нельзя ничё ставить", раз тачки в одной сети под доменом? Тыжадмин.

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь Вам необходимо убедиться, что WSMan and WinRM разрешены на удаленной машине:

```
Enable-PSRemoting –force
# Set start mode to automatic
Set-Service WinRM -StartMode Automatic
# Verify start mode and state - it should be running
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "WinRM"}
# Trust all hosts
Set-Item WSMan:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *
# Verify trusted hosts configuration
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

Проще всего запустить программу на удаленном хосте, используя сессии.

```
$s = New-PSSession -computername NAME -credential LOGIN
    Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {C:\folder\app.exe}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Другой способ:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName Computer1 -ScriptBlock { param ($myarg) & 'C:\Program Files\program.exe' -something $myarg } -ArgumentList "myArgValue"
```

ArgumentList - это массив аргументов, передаваемых для запуска (если они требуются).